# Recursively rename files and folders in Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm new to powershell and I am trying to rename any files and folders that have OC in the name. The following code I wrote works for the current directory, but I'm not sure how to recursively check all child files/folders.

```
get-childitem | Where-Object {  $_.Name -match "OC"} | Rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^......', 'OC9999'}
```

Edit:

```
get-childitem -recurse | Where-Object {  $_.Name -match "OC"} | Rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\d{4}', '8888'}
```

I have changed the code to the above and while it works, it must be run twice for the files inside the folder to be changed. The first run only catches the folder itself for some reason.

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem -recurse` to get all descendants, should do.

Comment: That works but for some reason I have to run it twice. The first execution changes the folder name but doesn't change any of the files in the folder. The second time I run the script, it changes the files. Why might this be?

Comment: Add `sort FullName -Descending` after `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: Because once you've changed the folder name, all paths below become invalid, so you had to do that again. Sorting should help indeed, because then files will be renamed before the folders they are in.,

Comment: @Vesper That makes a lot of sense, thanks!